Computing the projective cover of a module over a ring of matrices.
Let $R$ be the ring $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $S= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ a left ideal of $R$.  I want to find the projective left cover of $R/S$, thinking $R/S$ as a left $R$- module. First and foremost, I pretty sure this ring is perfect (thus it makes sense to think in it's projective cover) since $R$ is artinian due to the finite number of ideals of $R$. So far, I've noticed that
considering the epimorphism from $\phi: R \to \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ given by $$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y  \\
0 & z
\end{pmatrix} \to x,$$
and the fact that $S= Ker(\phi)$ it yields by the first isomorphism theorem that $R / S \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, right? So this reduces the problem to find the projective cover of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ thought as a $R$ left module. But still I'm out of ideas about findin the superfluous epimorphism covering $R/S$ as I can only thing of $R$ with the canonical epimorphism. Thanks :)

Hint: $S$ is a direct summand of $R$.

@DanielArreola Thanks Daniel. Yes, I agree $S \oplus S' = R$ where $S'= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2}  & 0 \
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. But how this can lead me to find the desired projective cover ?

Are you familiar with the fact that direct summands of free modules are projective? How are the modules $S'$ and $R/S$ related?

@DanielArreola  Then we need to see $S' $ or a quotient of $S'$ as a direct summand of $R/S$?

Linking to your other question. I'm not sure I approve of the practice of not linking this yourself. At least I wasted a bit of time explaining things that were covered here already.

@JyrkiLahtonen I'm sorry to hear that. I was not acquainted with the practice of linking previous questions. I'm here on and off. I tried to try some ideas from here previously but I couldn't figured out by myself. My bad.

We have $R \cong S \oplus S'$ as you described in the comments. This implies $R/S \cong S'$ is projective, as it is a direct summand of a free module.

Thanks Daniel!!!
